# Deleting row in table with Jquery in mvc project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I generate the following `html` code

```
<table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listUsers.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.listUsers[i].Name)</td>
                <td>   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.listUsers[i].Phone) </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="delete" data-id="@Model.listUsers[i].ID">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

I want to delete a row,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#delete").on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                tr.remove();
            });
    });

</script>
```

Executing this, the row is deleted but it only works the first time, i.e., only once.

How I can delete any row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IDs in HTML must be unique**, use a class instead then you can use [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

> Selects all elements with the given class.

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.listUsers[i].ID">Delete</button>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete").on("click", function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        tr.remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are generating duplicate `id` attributes for your button which is invalid html and the script will only be called once because you then delete the button. Instead remove the `id` and use a class name instead

```
<button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.listUsers[i].ID">Delete</button>
```

and modify the script to

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  tr.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are rendering a button with same `id` multiple times which is invalid `html` and every time you apply a selector on it, it selects the first element it finds in **DOM** with id **deleted**. Make the `id` unique by appending the id that is coming in Model and add a `class` attribute to the button:

```
<button type="button" class="delete" id="delete_@(Model.listUsers[i].ID)" data-id="@Model.listUsers[i].ID">Delete</button>
```

Now apply a click event on the class:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this id with class because the id duplicate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".delete").on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                tr.remove();
            });
 });


</script>

<tr>

<td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.listUsers[i].Name)</td>
<td>   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.listUsers[i].Phone) </td>
<td>
    <button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.listUsers[i].ID">Delete</button>
</td>
```