# Edit/Delete array row from table MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a **classroom** that have **an array of enrollments** as you can see below.

Classroom Model:

```
public class Classroom
    {
        public virtual int ClassroomId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Enrollment> EnrollmentsClassroom { get; set; }
        public Turma()
        {
            EnrollmentsClassroom = new List<Enrollment>();
        }
    }
```

Enrollment Model:

```
public class Enrollment
    {
        public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ClassroomId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
        public virtual Classroom ClassroomEnrollment { get; set; }
    }
```

I made a table that shows **all the enrollments from a particular classroom**:

View:

```
  @model X.Models.Classroom

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Planificacao";
            }

            <h2>Planificacao</h2>

        //this table only shows whats in the array of enrollments from the classroom choosen by the user
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model.EnrollmentsClassroom) //Name of the array of enrollments in model classroom
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
//obviously these ActionLinks are wrong:
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Enrollment", new { id = Model.ClassroomId }, null))
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Enrollment", new { id = Model.ClassroomId }, null))
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
```

My question is how can i edit and delete one row from the table since the view is using the Classroom model but the row is from the Enrollment, since i can't get the enrollment id in this way.
I already saw this post ([Deleting row in table with Jquery in mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876498/deleting-row-in-table-with-jquery-in-mvc-project)) but it didn't worked for me.
Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `item` in your foreach is an `Enrollment`, you can use it to access  enrollment data:

```
@foreach (Enrollment item in Model.EnrollmentsClassroom) {
     /* snip */
     @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Enrollment", new { id = item.EnrollmentId }, null))
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Enrollment", new { id = item.EnrollmentId }, null))
     /* snip */
}
```