# Html Table with button per row doesn't pass data to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

**Context**

I'm developing a form in ASP.NET MVC 4 with Bootstrap 3 which displays an entity framework derived table.  The table is read-only except that there is a button in the first column of each row allowing that row to be deleted.

My ViewModel:

```
public class SearchQueueViewModel
{
    public List<SearchURL> SearchUrls { get; set; }

    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid url")]
    [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Url must be 500 characters or less")]
    [Required]
    public string NewUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The table is coded like this:

```
@model SearchQueueViewModel

@foreach (UserInterface.Models.SearchURL row in Model.SearchUrls)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("delete", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <input type="hidden" value="@row" name="searchURL" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs">X</button>
            }
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.URL)</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@row.DateAdded.ToString("d-MMM-yy HH:mm")</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.Status)</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.SearchStarted)</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.SearchCompleted)</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.NumberOfProductsSearched)</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.NumberOfProductsFound)</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => row.FailErrorMessage)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(SearchURL searchURL)
    {
        context.SearchURLs.Remove(searchURL);
        context.SaveChanges();

        viewModel.SearchUrls = context.SearchURLs.ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**Issue**

The controller always receives a null object

**Question**

How do I get the searchURL object from the button-clicked row passed back to the controller correctly?

Comment: `value="@row"` is not the right way of doing it... just use a `Id` here and submit your `id` to controller.. And using this Id delete the record.

Comment: I'm with Raj.  You can't put an object in an HTML hidden field.  It has to be a string.

Comment: Ok so I've changed the input tag to value="@row.SearchURLId" and changed the controller to public ActionResult Delete(string searchURL).  That seems to work in that data is passed. So does this mean that unless I'm referencing my ViewModel in the controller I can only ever pass back strings?

Comment: @ifinlay I'm pretty sure you cannot set objects as a value for a hidden input. However, what you can do is in your form, if you create an input (hidden or not) for the different properties of your ViewModel, the ViewModel binder will automatically bind them to the properties of the parameters of your controller action (providing it's of the right type)

Comment: @ifinlay Also, you can pass any base data type in the HTTP request, although during the request they will transferred as strings (and converted on the server)

Comment: What is the property of `SearchURL` that is its unique identifier. Its that value that your need to post (and it can be just added as a route parameter - no hidden inputs are required)

Comment: @FrancisLord Thanks for that.  I'd prefer to be passing data both ways via the model but here I have the issue of acting on a button click on a specific row.  I could add check boxes instead of buttons and have these bound to the model but that's another click the user would have to make.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's broadly what I've ended up doing.  It's disappointing though as I've had to pass this to the controller, then convert it to an integer, then reread the row through Entity Framework before being able to delete it. Ah well. Happy to accept this as the answer if you'll do the necessary.

Comment: What do you mean _convert it to an integer_ - the method just needs to be `public ActionResult Delete(int id)` - no conversion is required. And you do not need to reread the row - Just initialize a new `SearchURL`, set its `ID`, `.Attach()` it to the context and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Note the for loop insted of foreach to enable model binding and the hidden fields to allow the values to be posted back to the controller. Change your view.

Your View:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SearchUrls.Count; i++)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("delete", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SearchUrls[i].SearchURLId)
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs">delete</button>
                }
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].SearchURLId.URL)</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">@Model.SearchUrls[i].DateAdded.ToString("d-MMM-yy HH:mm")</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].Status)</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].SearchStarted)</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].SearchCompleted)</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].NumberOfProductsSearched)</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].NumberOfProductsFound)</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SearchUrls[i].FailErrorMessage)</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And also change your Delete method.

```
  public ActionResult delete(SearchQueueViewModel sm) // note this line
      {
                //your code
      }
```

But the job is not finished yet. If I am not wrong now you are going to face issue with multiple submit button with identical property.

The best approach for your requirement is using javascript. You can have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876498/deleting-row-in-table-with-jquery-in-mvc-project)

Comment: This will not work - the `DefaultModelBinder` requires indexers to start at zero and be consecutive so only the first button would ever post back a value